# React Router add content to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't resolve some trouble with react router. I have two components: Login and ChoiceScreen. In Login component I have link to ChoiceScreen component, but when I click that it renders ChoiceScreen component content in my Login component content(I have in that part rendered two components content). When I go to /choices it renders well(only ChoiceScreen component content). After click link to ChoiceScreen I want to load only that component. I leave my current code below. Any advice?

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <div>       
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/choice" component={ChoiceScreen} />
          </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Login.js

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="login-form">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="top">
            <img src={logo} id="logo-login" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-area">
            <div className="group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="username"
                name="username"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder="Username"
              />
              <FontAwesomeIcon className="login-icon" icon="user" />
            </div>

            <div className="group">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <FontAwesomeIcon className="login-icon" icon="key" />
            </div>

            <div className="checkbox-login-container">
              <label className="container-label">
                Remember Me
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <span className="checkmark" />
              </label>
            </div>

            <input
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-default btn-block"
              id="login-btn"
              value="LOGIN"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/choice">Choices</Link>
          <Route path="/choice" component={ChoiceScreen} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please let me know version of react-router you are using.

Comment: I use 4.3.1 version.

Comment: Remove <Router> in Login.js

Answer (score 0):

Delete `<Route path="/choice" component={ChoiceScreen} />` from Login component.

Comment: After that when I clicked on link then only path was changed and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try with
`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";`

And inside render

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <div>
             <Switch>     
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login} exact />
              <Route path="/choice" component={ChoiceScreen} />
             </Switch>
          </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need several fixes to make this work

You cannot use "Router" directly without passing browser history in React Router 4

[image: Edit 10ryl7w0m3]